# Comments are shown twice when posted through AJAX, but appear only once on page reloads

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I used the following codes to add comment to a post and display it without refreshing the page, but somehow, it displays the comment twice instead of once, but it only saves it once in the database. When I refresh the page, it displays each comment only once though, so i guess the problem is with the "ajax response". Here are the codes, thanks for any help.

JavaScript:

```
function addComment(pid) {
    var url;
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    xml_http = getXmlHttpObject();
    if (xml_http == null) return alert("Your browser is too old to run this page!");
    url = '../auth.php?comment=' + comment + '&pid=' + pid;
    url += '&p=' + Math.random();
    xml_http.onreadystatechange = commentStatus;
    xml_http.open("GET", url, true);
    xml_http.send(null);
}

function commentStatus() {
    $("#comm").append(xml_http.responseText);
}
```

PHP:

```
include_once('include/comment.php');
addComment($_GET['pid'], filter($_GET['comment'])); 
if(empty($_SESSION['pic'])) $pic = "images/silh.gif"; 
else $pic = "/profile/image.php/{$_SESSION['uname']}.{$_SESSION['pic']}?width=45&amp;cropratio=1:1&amp;image=/profile/pix/{$_SESSION['uname']}.{$_SESSION['pic']}";
echo "<div id='comments'>\n"
    ."<img src='{$pic}' align='left' style='padding-right:5px' />"
    ."<span id='bluetxt'>By {$_SESSION['uname']}</span><br />\n"
    ."<span>Posted Now</span>\n"
    ."<br /><br /><p style='clear:both'>{$_GET['comment']}</p>"
    . "</div><br />\n";
```

I purposely don't read the comment from the database, I simply post it back on the page.

Comment: Down voted because of useless title. Modified title :)

Comment: You're using jQuery; why don't you use its Ajax functions? BTW, possible [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS) found: *always* use `htmlspecialchars` or `encodeurl` (depending on use case) when outputting user data to a web page.

Comment: BTW, you're using a global variable without any necessity (`xml_http`). Please don't! And use `encodeURIComponent` to properly encode query parameters. And perhaps you shouldn't use a `GET` request to update your database, `GET` requests should be idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should append the comment only when xml_http state is 4. Try it like this:

```
function addComment(pid) {
    var url;
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    var xml_http = getXmlHttpObject();

    if (xml_http == null)
         return alert("Your browser is too old to run this page!");

    url = '../auth.php?comment=' + comment + '&pid=' + pid;
    url += '&p=' + Math.random();

    xml_http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xml_http.readyState==4) {
            appendComment(xml_http.responseText);
        }
    };

    xml_http.open("GET", url, true);
    xml_http.send(null);
}

function appendComment(commentHTML) {
    $("#comm").append(commentHTML);
}
```

Comment: …and while you're at it, please get rid of the global variable and check `xml_http.status`.

Comment: Well, we can disagree about this, but I think if someone can give an answer that tells more than the questioner asked, but prevents them from other errors, one should do so. Otherwise Chibuzo will soon be back with a question like “Why is my `responseText` empty?” or “Why did my `xml_http` variable change?”

Comment: I prefer just to stick to answering questions that have actually been asked and not disorientate people who possibly aren't there yet to know what a global variable is and how to avoid using it;)

Comment: I already thought that. But I fear there are many people here that just copy-paste plainly bad tutorials and just don't read good material. I think that one should learn to use a language like JavaScript before experimenting with AJAX requests, where all kinds of things can go wrong. I've even seen a question here about such a request without a callback handler. But I'm Ok with your attitude, it's not something worth a big debate, let alone to pull each others hair out of our heads.

Comment: @all, I've localized the xml_http variable, but when I call it from the xml_http_onReadyStateChange() function, I get an error that the variable is undefined. I tried using this code instead   
        $("#frmCom").submit(function() {
  $.post("../auth.php", $("#frmCom").serialize(), function(data) {
   $("#comm").append(xml_http.responseText);
  });
 return false;  
 });    
 I modified the form accordingly but the code did nothing. Please what is wrong with it? Thank you

Comment: @Chibuzo: I have updated my example to make it work with local xml_http instance. Let me know if this helps.